# Why do these jQuery selectors with htmlfor work this way?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given this HTML:

```
<p htmlfor="afield">This field is required.</p>
```

this jQuery selector will find the p tag:

```
var filtered = $("*").filter("[for='afield']");
```

while this one will not:

```
$("p").filter("[for='afield']");
```

Why does the first one match? The attribute in the HTML is "htmlfor" and in the selector it's "for".

And, why does the second one *not* match?

Here's a Fiddle (with alerts, sorry...).

http://jsfiddle.net/f7v4h/1/

Editing to explain why I care, from the comments:

I am using the jquery-validate plugin. `[for='afield']` is the syntax the plugin code uses, and it's the plugin that is generating the HTML as well. I'm just trying to understand what's going on so I can fix a bug on my site.

Comment: Just a side note: in jquery 1.7 it doesn't work in both cases (as expected)

Comment: Why don't you use `[htmlfor='afield']`?

Comment: Good question. I am using the jquery-validate plugin and I'm trying to figure out what's going on with a situation on my site. `[for='afield']` is the syntax the plugin code uses, and it's the plugin that is generating the HTML as well.

Comment: This strikes me as a bug.  I'm digging to see if I can find the actual ticket that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade jQuery validate to 1.9.0 to see if it resolves the concern.  You can live-link it from Microsoft's CDN: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js

EDIT:

It seems that upgrading jQuery and jQuery.validate resolved the "it isn't working" but not the "why".  Attempting to answer the "why":

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-213157251 seems to suggest that these properties are exceptions and are thus renamed in awkward ways.  Perhaps this is another great example of jQuery abstracting away annoying browser abnormalities so we can just get the job done.

Comment: Upgrading the validate plugin does resolve the problem, but I still don't understand why. The generated HTML is still `<p htmlfor="email">This field is required.</p>`. The JS now says `.filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr('for') == name;
    });` which isn't different -- it's still looking for a `for` attribute when it's actually `htmlfor`.